# How to dynamically size the height and border of a ListView in View.Tile?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, listview, tiles

In a C# Winforms Application I have a ListView control.

I am using the View.Tile mode and have run into two issues:

1. The Tile truncates at a certain height (I haven't manually set anything).  How do I get it to expand to fit the text?
2. The Tile view doesn't show a border - how do I get the border to show?  Or is the border issue related to #1?  I have tried setting the GridLines property to true but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using the TileSize property of the ListView to change your tile height. [TileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.tilesize.aspx)
2. GridLines only works when your View is set to Details. [GridLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.gridlines.aspx)